# Why is there only limited usage of thread pools in TensorFlow-Federated?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

TFF's [threading libraries](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/cc/core/impl/executors/threading.h) start a new thread from [`ThreadRun` by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/cc/core/impl/executors/threading.h#L93), and the only usage (as of TFF 0.42.0) of the optional ThreadPool parameter is in the implementation of a single executor. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

After conferring with some people who were close to the implementation, the understanding we came to was:

The issue with totally general usage of thread pools in TFF is generally that if used incorrectly, we may be courting deadlock. We need FIFO scheduling in the thread pool itself, and FIFO-compatible usage in the runtime (if you need the result of a computation, you need to *know* it will be started before you start).

When implementing the first usages of thread pools in the TF executor, we reasoned ourselves to believing the following statement is true: at the leaf executors (that is, so long as an executor doesnt have any children), this FIFO-compatible programming is guaranteed by the stateful executor interface. That is, if you need a value, you know it has already been created (otherwise the executor wouldn't be able to resolve it), so as long as the thread pool is FIFO, it will be ready *before* you execute. Either the creating function already pushed a function onto this FIFO queue, or just created the value directly, so you can push yourself onto the FIFO queue no sweat.

Due to difficulty, we haven't really tried to reason too hard about how / whether we might be able to make similar statements about executors which have children (and these children may be pushing work onto the queue; AFAIK we dont really currently make any guarantees about *how* we do this, but i could imagine reasoning about a similar invariant step-by-step 'up the stack'). Thus we have only considered it safe so far to inject thread pool usage at leaf executors. The fact that we don't have this in the XLAExecutor yet is simply due to lack of use.